Get wix Form Collection
I have a Wix Form Collection from adding a form directly into my page, so for each submission made, it is added to the form submission table. I am trying to access the content in it through code in wix, however I'm having difficulty querying to form collection as I can't find the ID of it.
Does anyone know how to actually obtain information in a wix form or how to set it up so I can.
